# should iuse WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); two times?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I have used [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in the main function so I should use the instruction  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  two times or one enough?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 .....
  runApp( MyApp());
}
```

Comment: No only one time, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873338/what-does-widgetsflutterbinding-ensureinitialized-do/63873689#63873689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One time initialization is enough.

If you look at `ensureInitialized()`'s source code,
all it does is to check whether the `WidgetsBinding` instance is `null` or not.
If it's `null`, a new instance is created.

Here's the function:

```dart
    static WidgetsBinding ensureInitialized() {
      if (WidgetsBinding.instance == null)
        WidgetsFlutterBinding();
      return WidgetsBinding.instance!;
    }
```