# Can't init sqlite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I'm trying init mysql db file in flutter.
I'm using this code:

```
  static Future<void> initdb() async {
    final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(databasePath, 'models.db');
    _database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE models(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, barcode TEXT, type TEXT, brand TEXT, color TEXT, gender TEXT, price REAL, total INTEGER)',
      );
    });
  }
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_svg: 2.0.4
  sqflite: 2.2.8
  path_provider: 2.0.14
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

In main.dart:

```
void main() async{
  await ModelDatabase.initdb();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
```

Also same error with example from official doc example from flutter
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

I tried to run flutter clean and revalidate caches.
Also not working.
I'm using Android Studio 2022.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I no longer remember where this is documented but typically you should add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before using any plugin API before `runApp` is called:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await ModelDatabase.initdb();
  ...
```

See [What Does WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873338/what-does-widgetsflutterbinding-ensureinitialized-do)